# condicional con comparador de datos

Tags: javascript, formato-condicional

una consulta tengo que definir una funcion X e Y, y ambas tienen que recibir un valor numerico, y como resultado retornar el mayor de ambos. No logro asignar bien los valores en la funcion para realizar el calculo. hizo esto pero no me cierra, como lo puedo cambiar, y que me recomiendan para leer sobre el tema . Mil gracias

```
function elMayor (var1, var2){
    let var1 = 10;
    let var2 = 5;

    if (var1 >= var2){
        return ('10');
    }else{
        return ('5');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es usar tus parametros, en vez de redeclararlos dentro de la función, por ejemplo, tu código quedaría así:

```js
function elMayor (var1, var2){
    if (var1 >= var2){
        return var1;
    }else{
        return var2;
    }

}

console.log(elMayor(5, 4));
```

Como vemos funciona, basta con usar aquellos numeros que le estas pasando, osea que ya no necesitas definir tus variables dentro:

```
let var1 = 10;
let var2 = 5;
```

Ni tampoco requieres hardcodear el resultado de retorno como lo estabas haciendo:

```
if (var1 >= var2){
    return ('10');
}else{
    return ('5');
}
```

En vez de ello el retorno es dinamico:

```
function elMayor (var1, var2){
    if (var1 >= var2){
        return var1;
    }else{
        return var2;
    }

}
```

De hecho hay una mejor forma de reescribir tu función, y es usando operaciones matemáticas que están declaradas para javascript con el objeto `Math`, checa tu misma función pero reducida:

```js
function elMayor (var1, var2){
    return Math.max(var1, var2);
}

console.log(elMayor(5, 4));
```

La funcion `max` se encarga de devolvernos el mayor valor numerico entre varios valores, **pueden ser varios, no solo dos**. por eso la considero un poco mas completa y potente.